# openshift installation on centos7 (vagrant virtual box on windows) is causing errorwith ports 80 and 443

Tags: windows, vagrant, openshift, virtualbox, centos7

I have a windows machine on which i have centos7 running inside virtualbox.
I am trying to install redhat openshift and make it work.  `enter code here`
The necessary steps are on https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md#linux.

Please help me resolve the following error.

I am getting the following error:

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# oc cluster up
-- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
-- Checking Docker client ... OK
-- Checking Docker version ... OK
-- Checking for existing OpenShift container ... OK
-- Checking for openshift/origin:v1.4.0-alpha.1 image ... OK
-- Checking Docker daemon configuration ... OK
-- Checking for available ports ... 
   WARNING: Port 80 is already in use and may cause routing issues for
applications.
   WARNING: Port 443 is already in use and may cause routing issues for
applications.
FAIL
   Error: Cannot get TCP port information from Kubernetes host
   Caused By:
     Error: cannot start container
db018a9349dda92ddb8d3cb95899de17698d059ca9ba68264fa72e03dcec0816
     Caused By:
       Error: API error (500): Failed to initialize logging driver: journald is not
enabled on this host
```

Here is my vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "boxcutter/centos72-desktop"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6080, host: 80
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6443, host: 443

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Comment: Do you have any existing processes running on port 80 and 443? You can use netstat -ao -n command to find the port numbers with their processes

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this in a CentOS VM? Even if you sort out the port issues, you will have trouble using OpenShift from the host (Windows) machine. Why don't you follow the Windows instructions - https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md#windows-with-docker-for-windows. Install Docker Toolbox for Windows and run 'oc cluster up' from your Windows host using as target the Docker daemon provided by Docker Toolbox.

Comment: I am getting an error when I use C\> oc cluster up --create-machine

C:\WINDOWS\system32>oc cluster up --create-machine

   Creating initial OpenShift configuration
FAIL
   Error: could not update OpenShift configuration
   Caused By:
     Error: API error (404): {"message":"lstat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0f6833a64a36ff25a712f90905aa952415a31fa622b55dfe992fa0c13476a61f/\\var\\lib\\origin\\openshift.local.config\\master: no such file or directory"}

Comment: The I took the suggestion to install on windows(as per Hardy's suggestion).  The problem was with oc version 1.4.0.  The problem did not occur when I used 1.3.0.

Comment: Suggestion is to use official `oc cluster up` method with docker for windows. For more info see: https://install.openshift.com/